# Настроить доступ с локального макбука к серверам без паролей

Tags: macos

Имеются два сервера: сервер1 и сервер2. Доступ осуществляется через ssh ключи. Необходимо настроить локальную машину (макбук) таким образом, чтобы доступ к серверам не запрашивал пароля - аутентификация проходила без запроса пароля. Как это осуществить?

Answer (score 1):

0. Запускаете терминал.
1. `ssh-keygen -t ed25519` (предпочитаю этот алгоритм. Как минимум - строка у него короче)
2. `ssh-copy-id user@host` - при этом спросит пароль
3. `ssh user@host` - теперь и далее будет работать уже без запроса пароля

При этом на сервере в конфиге sshd должно быть `PubkeyAuthentication yes`

Comment: Я все так и делал, только файл конфига менял на локальной машине. И с перезапуском файла конфига на маке командой systemctl reload sshd.service выскакивала ошибка: на маке нет такой команды. Оказывается файл конфига надо менять на сервере. Сейчас попробуй. Спасибо за ответ